# Prove fact using matrix multiplcation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations

Prove $F_αR_θF_α = R_{−θ}$.

I'm trying to prove that this fact holds true, where $F_\theta$ is the reflection matrix (assuming $\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $R_\theta$ is the rotation matrix.

$R_\theta =   \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\ \theta & -sin\ \theta \\
     sin\ \theta & cos\ \theta
  \end{bmatrix}
$, $F_\theta =   \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\ \theta & sin\ \theta \\
     sin\ \theta & -cos\ \theta
  \end{bmatrix}
$

Performing routine matrix multiplication, I get for the left hand side,  \begin{bmatrix}
    cos^2(α) cos(\theta) & -sin^2(α) sin(\theta) \\
     sin^2(α) sin(\theta) & cos^2(α) cos(\theta))
  \end{bmatrix}

And the right, \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\ \theta & sin\ \theta \\
     -sin\ \theta & cos\ \theta
  \end{bmatrix}.

Which aren't equal? What mistake am I making?

Comment: Could you give more detail about how you computed the LHS? It looks like your are multiplying the matrices elementwise instead of using matrix multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: May have been a mistake but since it's a tedious computation, I simply plugged it into Wolfram and got that as my result.

Comment: Mathematica, and I assume Wolfram|Alpha, too, performs element-by-element multiplication if you simply juxtapose the matrices. If you want matrix multiplication, you have to specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct calculation of the LHS gives:
$\begin{pmatrix}\ \sin(\alpha)^2\cos(\theta)+\cos(\alpha)^2\cos(\theta)&\ \sin(\alpha)^2\sin(\theta)+\cos(\alpha)^2\sin(\theta)\\
  -\sin(\alpha)^2\sin(\theta)-\cos(\alpha)^2\sin(\theta)&\sin(\alpha)^2\cos(\theta)+\cos(\alpha)^2\cos(\theta) 
\end{pmatrix}$

 which after using $\sin(\alpha)^2+\cos(\alpha)^2=1$ gives the desired result.